# About Security Tips of using Android Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I read the Android official Security Tips of using Intent:
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips#use-intents

And I'm confused by the following usage scenario:

> "Senders of an intent can verify that the recipient has permission by specifying a non-null permission with the method call."

Could someone give me an example about how the intent sender can verify the recipient has permission, and how to specify an non-null permission in the Intent object?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect it has to do with Intent filtering.  Check here for a discussion of that:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124804/android-intent-syntax

Comment: Best example provided by google https://developer.android.com/topic/security/best-practices

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, I just need to the specific example for this case: "Senders of an intent can verify that the recipient has permission by specifying a non-null permission with the method call."